# Failed assertion: line 1916 pos 14: 'children != null': is not true.?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been trying to run a flutter app and it keeps giving me Failed assertion error. below is my code. I just want to show the list the second code

```
     class Post extends StatefulWidget {
      final String postId;
      final String ownerId;
      final String username;
      final String location;
      final String description;
      final String mediaUrl;
      final dynamic likes;
    
      Post({
        this.postId,
        this.ownerId,
        this.username,
        this.location,
        this.description,
        this.mediaUrl,
        this.likes,
      });
    
      factory Post.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        return Post(
          postId: doc['postId'],
          ownerId: doc['ownerId'],
          username: doc['username'],
          location: doc['location'],
          description: doc['description'],
          mediaUrl: doc['mediaUrl'],
          likes: doc['likes'],
        );
      }
    
      int getLikeCount(likes) {
        // if no likes, return 0
        if (likes == null) {
          return 0;
        }
        int count = 0;
        // if the key is explicitly set to true, add a like
        likes.values.forEach((val) {
          if (val == true) {
            count += 1;
          }
        });
        return count;
      }
    
      @override
      _PostState createState() => _PostState(
            postId: this.postId,
            ownerId: this.ownerId,
            username: this.username,
            location: this.location,
            description: this.description,
            mediaUrl: this.mediaUrl,
            likes: this.likes,
            likeCount: getLikeCount(this.likes),
          );
    }
    
    class _PostState extends State<Post> {
      final String postId;
      final String ownerId;
      final String username;
      final String location;
      final String description;
      final String mediaUrl;
      Int likeCount;
      Map likes;
    
      _PostState({
        this.postId,
        this.ownerId,
        this.username,
        this.location,
        this.description,
        this.mediaUrl,
        this.likes,
        this.likeCount,
      });
    
      Widget postingHeading() {
        return FutureBuilder(
            future:
                FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('User').doc(ownerId).get(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              return ListTile(
                onTap: () => print('go check the url'),
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage:
                      NetworkImage("${snapshot.data.data()['photoUrl']}"),
                ),
                title: Text('${snapshot.data.data()['username']}'),
                subtitle: Text(location),
                trailing: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => print('deleting post'),
                  icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
                ),
              );
            });
      }
    
      Widget postImagePicture() {
        return Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            Image.network(mediaUrl),
          ],
        );
      }
    
      Widget postDetailsComment() {
        return Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border), onPressed: () {}),
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border), onPressed: () {})
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "$likeCount likes",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(username),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 1,
                ),
                Flexible(child: Text(description))
              ],
            )
          ],
        );
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            postingHeading(),
            postImagePicture(),
            postDetailsComment(),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

here is where I convert it to List... I don't even no what is wrong.... please help.... thanks in advance

```
    class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
  final String currentUser;
  Profile({this.currentUser});

  @override
  _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
}

class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  int postLenght;
  List<Post> post;
  bool pleaseWait;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUsersPicsDetails();
  }

  getUsersPicsDetails() async {
    setState(() {
      pleaseWait = false;
    });
    QuerySnapshot _getPost = await _firestore
        .collection('post')
        .doc(widget.currentUser)
        .collection('userPost')
        .orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true)
        .get();
    setState(() {
      pleaseWait = true;
      postLenght = _getPost.docs.length;
      post = _getPost.docs.map((e) => Post.fromDocument(e)).toList();
      print(postLenght);
    });
  }

  fellowEditButtton({String test, Function press}) {
    return TextButton(
      onPressed: press,
      child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: 25,
          width: 250,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              border: Border.all(),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
          child: Text(
            test,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          )),
    );
  }

  gettingUserprofile() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _firestore.collection('User').doc(widget.currentUser).snapshots(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.active) {
          return Text('this stuff en');
        }
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 1,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          FullScreenWidget(
                            child: Hero(
                              tag: 'smallImage',
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                    '${snapshot.data.data()['photoUrl']}'),
                                radius: 50.0,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                  children: [
                                    topColum(buttom: 'Post', number: 1),
                                    topColum(buttom: 'Fellowers', number: 2),
                                    topColum(buttom: 'Following', number: 0),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 20.0,
                                        ),
                                        child: widget.currentUser ==
                                                _auth.currentUser.uid
                                            ? fellowEditButtton(
                                                test: 'Edit Profile',
                                                press: profileEditingButton)
                                            : fellowEditButtton(
                                                test: 'Fellow', press: () {})),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),

                      Divider(),
                      //! this is  i call the list
                      //getUserPicture(),
                      getUserPicture(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ));
      },
    );
  }

  profileEditingButton() {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => EditProfile(
                  userProfile: widget.currentUser,
                )));
  }

  Widget topColum({int number, String buttom}) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text(
          '$number',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          buttom,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

//! this is the where i return the list
  Widget getUserPicture() {
    if (pleaseWait = false) {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
    return Column(
      children: post,
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: header(context, titleString: "Profile"),
        body:
            //Text('${widget.currentUser}')
            gettingUserprofile());
    // userPictursPost(),
  }
}
```

I want to the get the post at the bottom... thanks in advance
below is the error image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvF1v.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get an error, please post it along with your question. When you are getting an error, it means that something is wrong with your code,and most likely not the flutter engine. Both are important for debugging, the error+your code.

Try changing this

```
QuerySnapshot _getPost = await _firestore
    .collection('post')
    .doc(widget.currentUser)
    .collection('userPost')
    .orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true)
    .get();
setState(() {
  pleaseWait = true;
  postLenght = _getPost.docs.length;
  post = _getPost.docs.map((e) => Post.fromDocument(e)).toList();
  print(postLenght);
});
```

into this:

```
QuerySnapshot _getPost = await _firestore
    .collection('post')
    .doc(widget.currentUser)
    .collection('userPost')
    .orderBy('timeStamp', descending: true)
    .get();
if(_getPost.docs.isNotEmpty){
List<Post> tempPost = _getPost.docs.map((e) => Post.fromDocument(e)).toList();
setState(() {
  pleaseWait = true;
  post =tempPost
 
  print(postLenght);
});
}else{
print('The List is empty);}
```

You are not checking if the Query result has data or not. If it's empty, you will pass an empty List post down your tree, and you will get the error you are having.

Comment: What is the 'causing widget', where are you getting null children.

Comment: yes, i cant just figur out what is the cause.... i try print the length of the document is given me 0.

Comment: This means that your query is returning no results! Check your query parameters, and it should work.

Comment: the error is from the query parameter, i just check well, the cause is from typo error.... but there is a problem again.... i first get the children null first before i shows the real result ... How can i solve this..... Thanks in advance

Comment: before you show your results, in the widget, check if the list is empty, by doing the following:
`post.isEmpty ? CircularProgressIndicator() : YOUR_LIST_BUILDER`

this will show a spinner as long as the list is empty. 
or this:

`post.isEmpty ? Text('No items yet') : YOUR_LIST_BUILDER`

Please confirm that this works.

Comment: @GbengaAyannuga you're most welcome, please upvote the helpful comments and kindly mark my answer as 'Answer'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For people facing similar issues, let me tell what I found in my code:

***The error says that the children is null, not empty !***

So if you are getting the children for the parent widget like Row or Column from a separate method, ***just check if you are returning the constructed child widget from the method***.

```
Row(
  children: getMyRowChildren()
)
.
.
.

getMyRowChildren(){
    Widget childWidget = ... //constructed
    return childWidget; //don't forget to return!
}
```

Else it would return null, which results in the children being null and we get the mentioned above error!